# PHP Totaling Each Array Data

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, sum

How to sum each array data like image below?

[image: IMAGE: totaling each array data]

Help me.

Comment: Whenever possible please put the text of your question in your question as text.

Comment: The obvious question. What have you tried? What's the code you have already written to solve this yourself?

Comment: It's unwise to store data with delimiters like that. It's not transparent, you can't query it. In other words, it violates the normal forms and you can bet it will make problems along the way of the software lifetime.

Answer (score -1):

```
$item_price = explode("#", $item_price);

$itemquantity = explode("#", itemquantity);

$result = array();

for($i = 0; $i < count(item_price); $i++)
{
    $result[] =  $item_price[i] * $itemquantity[i]);
}
```

Comment: Indenting with four spaces or using the `{}` button formats code correctly. There's no need for the `<code>` tag.

Comment: Please try to come up with an answer that explains your solution. Code only answers aren't very appreciated on SO.